# Having a problem with applying realm plugin to gradle file

Tags: android, realm

I wanted to apply realm to my project,
It went well, I added jcenter() repositories and synced it which had no problem. But when I went to the buildgradle(Module:3_8), and added a code:

```
apply plugin:'realm-android'
```

this error was raised:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':part3_8'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'realm-android'.
   > Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'BintrayJCenter' was added by plugin 'realm-android'
```

this is my build.gradle(project:letmein)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is where the problem is:

```
//plugins {
//    id 'com.android.application'
////    id 'realm-android'
//}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'




android {
    compileSdk 31
```

(plus, I use Android studio:)

Answer (score 0):

In gradle settings replace the line

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

With

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
```